# Heads of strings having tails following a certain pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I receive strings that can be equal to `any + " " + str + "Y"` where `any` can be any string and where the string `str` can be equal to `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, `"5"`, `"7"` or `"10"`. My goal is to extract the string `any`.

I came up with the following code :

```
string pattern = ".* {1Y|2Y|3Y|5Y|7Y|10Y}";
string indexIDTorParse = group.ElementAt(0).IndexID;
Match result = Regex.Match(indexIDTorParse, pattern);
string IndexIDTermBit = result.Value;
string IndexID = indexIDTorParse.Replace($" {IndexIDTermBit}", "");
```

but it doesn't give the right `any`.

Comment: So your input string ends with a space followed by 1Y or 2Y etc....?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing a substring from 0 to last index of space? How do you receive the input?

Comment: A tool I find very useful, is https://regex101.com/ it makes working regular expressions a breeze.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It really was, many thx !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of braces, you should use [**parentheses**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that will define a group of patterns, and you may *capture* the `any` part and access it directly via [**`Match.Groups`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than additionally replace the input string:

```
string pattern = @"(.*) (?:[1-357]|10)Y";
string indexIDTorParse = group.ElementAt(0).IndexID;
Match result = Regex.Match(indexIDTorParse, pattern);
string IndexID = "";
if (result.Success) 
{
    IndexID = result.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

The regex matches:

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars, as many as possible (**NOTE** if you need to get the substring up to the first occurrence of `nY`, use `(.*?)`, it will match as few chars as possible before the subsequent patterns)
- - a space
- `(?:[1-357]|10)` - `1`, `2,`3`,`5`,`7`or`10`
- `Y` - a `Y` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/haqZaC/1).